# How to integrate recaptcha with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, recaptcha

I'm using Devise for authentication and want to add captcha in registration form, I've read about recaptcha,can someone tell how to integrate both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google showed a page on the devise wiki - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

Have you looked at that?

Comment: It's throwing an error which says "No private key specified."

Comment: Have you got a private key for recaptcha (step 1)

Answer (score 7):

1. [obtain a reCAPTCHA API key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin)
2. [Install gem ReCaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)
3. Add `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` to your view (`views/devise/registrations/new`)
4. Create file (in `config/initializers`) recaptcha.rb and add this code:

   ```
   Recaptcha.configure do |config|
     config.public_key  = 'Your public key'
     config.private_key = 'Your private key'
   end
   ```
5. Create in controller: `registrations_controller.rb` and add this code

   ```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
     def create
       if verify_recaptcha
         super
       else
         build_resource(sign_up_params)
         clean_up_passwords(resource)
         flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."
         flash.delete :recaptcha_error
         render :new
       end
     end
   end
   ```
6. Update your devise route for:

   ```
   devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
   ```